# Protocol function with Self type

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, protocols

Here is the code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@protocol HomeHeaderCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didTapMoreLessMenuButton:(HomeHeaderCell *)cell;
@end

@interface HomeHeaderCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *secondMenuRowView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *moreLessMenuButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *secondMenuRowViewHeightConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *askButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *contactButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *benchmarkButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buySellButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *marketButton;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <HomeHeaderCellDelegate> delegate;
@property BOOL isFullMenu;

- (void)toggleHeight;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

This line has error

```
- (void)didTapMoreLessMenuButton:(HomeHeaderCell *)cell;
```

it says:

> Expected a type

Comment: Yes. What is your question?

Comment: I want to add `HomeHeaderCell` as parameter, but it says error. I want to solve that error.

Comment: No, is says *Expected a type* (there is no one). Did you try to add `@class HomeHeaderCell;` above the protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs to know that the class `HomeHeaderCell` is declared somewhere.

Actually you have to **import** the class with an `@import` statement but in this case you need only the type but not the implementation details. The `@class` directive is a forward reference which confirms the type but avoids circular reference issues.

Add `@class` under the import line, by the way use the modern `@import` statement.

```
@import UIKit;
@class HomeHeaderCell;
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, what about an explanation why this is necessary? It's called an forward-declaration to tell the compiler there will be a class defined sometime later. While the protocol is defined, the HomeHeaderCell is not known to the compiler. It basically says, 'This is OK, class implementation will follow'

Answer (score 0):

you can do it

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@protocol HomeHeaderCellDelegate;

@interface HomeHeaderCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <HomeHeaderCellDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol HomeHeaderCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didTapMoreLessMenuButton:(HomeHeaderCell *)cell;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Comment: This way `HomeHeaderCellDelegate` will not specified!